# How to call a GWT method from javascript code

Tags: gwt, gxt

I am using following block of code in ListView of Gxt component, and onRender the following template will be set to the default. I could able to render the component with image + model value. I want to write onClick event for rendered image.

**Here the place i am setting template to ListView.**

```
 rightListView.setTemplate(getTemplate(moduleBaseURL));
```

**template setting :**

```
private native String getTemplate(String base) /*-{  
return ['<tpl for=".">',  
'<div class="thumb"><img src="'+base+'images/default/tabs/tab-close.gif" width="15" height="15" style="CURSOR:pointer"/>{bookCode}</div>',  
'</div>',  
'</tpl>',  
''].join("");
```

}-*/;

**Screen Shot**:

[image]

On click of close image, i have some gwt code to be executed, is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.. you can write native javascript inside your gwt code.

```
    public static native void exportMyFunction() /*-{
       $wnd.myFunction =
          $entry(@com.myCompany.myProject.client.myClass::onCloseGwtFunction()());
    }-*/;
    public static void onCloseGwtFunction()
    {
       // your gwt code to be executed 
    }
```

When your app is initializing you must call exportMyFunction() from gwt class. and you can give

```
<img onClick='window.myFunction()' src="'+base+'images/default/tabs/tab-close.gif" width="15" height="15" style="CURSOR:pointer" />
```

in your onclick from your close image

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Now i could able to write the listener for img onClick event.

Comment: Can non static methods be called this way?

Answer (score 1):

In production Java will be translated into JavaScript code, that will be [obfuscated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_%28software%29) - not readable by humans. Therefore you cannot just compile your application and then call some class you have in your project as it will be renamed during compilation.

What you can do is export one of the methods, so it will be available globally. Then you will be able to call that exported Java method from JavaScript.

Communication between Java->JS and JS->Java is done using JSNI[JavaScript Native Interface] explained in GWT documentation under this link:

> > [Calling a Java Method from Handwritten JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI#calling).